# ReCaptcha in VUEjs and firebase not working "not an object:

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, recaptcha

I am trying to get a user signed in using a phone number on a popup:
This is a child element that pops up and allows the user to input what you see in thecode and sign in. In order for the # to be used there must be a recaptcha that is attached to the sign in button, but it tells me it is not an object when the ID is the same.

'''

```
<template>
  <div class="login-card">
    <div class="post-card">
      <div class="post-header">
        <button class="close-button" @click="closePopup">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="post-content">
        <h2>Create Account</h2>
        <form @submit.prevent="">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              v-model="email"
              placeholder="Phone or email"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" v-model="password" required />
          </div>
          <button id="sign-in-button" type="submit" @click="register">
            Register
          </button>
          {{ email }}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithPhoneNumber,
  updateProfile,
  RecaptchaVerifier,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

const email = ref("");
const password = ref("");
const auth = getAuth();

const router = useRouter();

const register = () => {
  window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, "sign-in-button", {
    size: "invisible",
    callback: (response) => {
      // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
      onSignInSubmit();
    },
  });

  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth(), email.value, password.value)
    .then(() => {
      updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
        displayName: "Jimmy",
      });
      router.push("/");
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};

const props = defineProps({
  closePopup: Function,
});
```

'''